# Can we pass self a default parameter in template parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a way to pass the class itself as a default value.

```
template<typename T, class NodeType>
class A: {
    public:
       virtual NodeType* foo() {}
};
template<typename T, class NodeType=B<T>>
class B: public A<T, NodeType> {
};
```

I am making a general node for trees.

BinaryTreeNode -> BSTNode -> AVLNode

Comment: Do you *want* the `NodeType` of `B` to be overridable?

Comment: I want to NodeType to default to B<T>

Comment: But, this way, `B<T>` is `B<T, B<T, B<T, B<T,......>>>>>`

Comment: Can you explain: WHY?

Comment: Is there any other way to implement this? I am making a general node for trees, which will be inherited by BSTNode which will be inherited by AVLNode.

Comment: What you probably want is this instead `template<typename T>     class B: public A<T, B<T>> {     };` If that will compile, or something close to this.

Comment: You are making this over complicated. Why do you need something like this? When I was doing BST tree didn't had to make such complex template. That is why I've asked: WHY?

Comment: I want to inherit all the functions I used for BST to be made available for AVL. Like, insert returns the inserted node itself. Using this pointer I can extend AVL insert to rebalance

Comment: `NodeType` vs `Node` is this a typo? Also `class A: {` doesnt look right and `;` are missing (i'd fix the `;` myself, but not sure about the rest)

Comment: *"I want to NodeType to default to B<T>"* - That did not at all answer my question.

Comment: StoryTeller - Unslander Monica: I want NodeType param to default to B<T>.
This is the context of the node for a tree. GeneralNode -> BSTNode -> AVLNode

Comment: Maybe is CRTP what you're looking for?

Comment: It doesn't solve for multilevel inheritence

Answer (score -3):

```
template<typename T, class NodeType>
class A {
public:
   virtual NodeType* foo() {}
};
template<class T, class NodeType=void>
class B:
  public A<T, typename std::conditional<std::is_same<NodeType,void>::value,B<T>,NodeType>::type>
{};
```

The trick here is `void` stands in for self.  When we use it we just conditionally swap in `B<T>`.